# Exception Handler does not catch custom exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I am working at a exception handler and a custom exception class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GeneralExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GeneralExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(ApiException.class)
    public static ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptions(ApiException e) {
        logger.info("Exception handled:" + e.getMessage() + " with http status: " + e.getHttpStatus());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), e.getHttpStatus());
    }
}
```

And

```
public class ApiException extends Exception{

    private final String message;
    private final HttpStatus httpStatus;

    public ApiException(String message, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        this.message = message;
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public HttpStatus getHttpStatus() {
        return httpStatus;
    }
}
```

When i throw an ApiException in my service class, it should be catched in controller layer but it doesn't work. These are my service and controller functions.

```
 @Override
    public Boolean deleteSubjectType(int subjectTypeId) throws ApiException {
    SubjectType subjectType=subjectTypeRepository.findById(subjectTypeId)
            .orElseThrow(()->new ApiException("Subject Type Id not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    return true;
    }
```

And

```
    @DeleteMapping("/{subjectTypeId}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteSubjectType(@PathVariable int subjectTypeId) {
    subjectTypeService.deleteSubjectType(subjectTypeId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, I found that it works fine. Make sure that spring can scan the folder where the GeneralExceptionHandler resides

Comment: It looks like the project structure is alright

Answer (score -1):

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GeneralExceptionHandler {
private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(GeneralExceptionHandler.class);

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public static ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptions(Exception e) {
    logger.info("Exception handled:" + e.getMessage() + " with http 
status: " + e.getHttpStatus());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), e.getHttpStatus());
  }
  }
```

Also add following code to your application.properties

```
   spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
   spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```